# NLP on powerbi on prem

Tags: nlp, powerbi

I am building a dashboard with power bi on prem (no cloud) and I want to add natural language processing component. What technologies should I be using as nlp is only available for power bi cloud and I cannot use it so I must think of another way, it's like the Q&A cloud solution equivalent for on prem

Answer (score 1):

There's really no good way.

You could use Azure's [Language Understanding Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-service/) to parse the natural language snippets, but Power BI Report Server doesn't have the [embedding APIs](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-report-authoring/wiki) you would need to translate the intents to visuals.  You could use the language to write a custom DAX or SQL query to get data, but you wouldn't be able to use Power BI Visualations, as you can't build visuals on-the-fly in Power BI Report Server.